# How to take simultaneous input and output in C?

Tags: c, concurrency, project, 2d-games

I am working on a project which is the popular "Snake Game". But I need a method which takes simultaneous input from user to change the direction of moving snake on the output screen.
As soon as the key to change direction is pressed, immediately the input should be processed and at output screen, the snake must move in the pressed direction.

Comment: What you are describing does not necessarily require concurrency.  Your game will perform screen updates at some fixed rate, so the effect of a user keystroke cannot be reflected any sooner than the next update.  Computers are fast; you should have plenty of time between refreshes to poll (without blocking) for input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using blocking I/O (where you make call to read from stdin or from keyboard and wait until the input comes), you need non-blocking I/O, which is provided by [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

The advantage of poll is that it returns right away, even if there is no keyboard input. As per the comment above, since the refreshes would be happening much much faster than the normal [human reaction time](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS747US747&ei=iXuJW_SYJcji_Ab9oLGwDg&q=human%20reaction%20time&oq=human%20reaction%20time&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.3798.5552.0.5629.19.14.0.4.4.0.129.993.11j2.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.17.1001...0i131k1j0i67k1j0i131i67k1j0i10k1.0.5RHR3nfraHY) (computers are fast), it will appear as though visual updates and keyboard processing happens simultaneously.

Comment: Yopu don't NEED non-blocking I/O.